# How do I derive this formula?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

How do I derive the range of a projectile formula?

$$d = \frac{v\cos\theta}{g} \left( v\sin\theta + \sqrt{v^2 \sin^2\theta+ 2gy_0} \right)$$

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: *or do they require to derive it from the kinematic formulas?* That is not knowable by the members of this site.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Maximum_distance_of_projectile

Comment: The formula is wrong so you better not use it.  The dimensions are all messed up.  The first term in the sum has dimensions of inverse acceleration.  The square root part is a velocity.

Comment: An editor has fixed the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive this from t = d/Vox. For more check out the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Maximum_distance_of_projectile

Answer (score 1):

I taught basic kinematics for forty years and never encountered that formula.  I would not have given a problem of that complexity on a test.  If given it as homework I would have expected a derivation or a reference.  To derive set t = d/ ${v_o}_x$, then put that expression for t in the, y, position equation.  Solving gives a quadratic equation for d.